# SAS Applying Dataset of column names to a proc import

Tags: import, sas, sas-macro

I have a very large dataset that I'm reading in, it is 2400 columns long. When I try and read this in via Proc Import it cuts off the variable names so instead I thought I could read in the column names first, then apply these to the data when I'm reading it in.

I've been working with the below code, the issue I'm having is it doesn't delimitate by the csv commas. So it doesn't read in properly.

```
data var_names;
    length var $300;
    infile 'mylocation/import_file.CSV' delimiter=',' obs=1  lrecl=40423;
    input var @@ ;
run;

data var_names;
set var_names;
    translated=compress(var, , 'kad');
run;


data _NULL_;
file "mylocation\read_file.sas";
set var_names end=fine;
if _N_=1 then do;
put "data imported_data;";
put "    length        ";
end;
put "       " translated       ;
if fine then
put "   $300;";
run;    


data _NULL_;
file "mylocation\read_file.sas" mod;
set var_names end=fine;
if  _N_=1 then do;
    put "infile 'mylocation\import_file.CSV' delimiter=',' firstobs=2  lrecl=40423;";
    put "input                                                                                        ";
end;
put "      " translated;
if fine then do; 
    put "    ;";
    put "run;";
end;
run;

%include "mylocation\read_file.sas";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the DSD option to properly read a delimited text file, like a CSV file.

```
Alice,F,13,,84
Barbara,F,,65.3,98
```

Otherwise SAS will treat multiple adjacent delimiters as a single delimiter.  Just like it would treat spaces in an ordinary text file that has extra spaces added in front of short values to make neat columns.

```
Alice   F 13    .  84
Barbara F  . 65.3  98
```

**So change your generated INFILE statement:**

```
put "infile 'mylocation\import_file.CSV' dsd firstobs=2 lrecl=40423;";
```

The default delimiter when using the DSD option is already a comma.

PROC IMPORT cannot handle header lines that are longer than 32,767 bytes.  If you want a tool that can analyze a delimited text file and create SAS code to read it try this macro :
https://github.com/sasutils/macros/blob/master/csv2ds.sas

If you are forced to stick with proc import then read the names separately and generate RENAME pairs for the names that are different than what PROC IMPORT generated.

Example:

```
filename csv 'myfilename.csv' lrecl=1000000;
proc import file=csv out=want replace dbms=csv; run;
data newnames ; infile csv dsd obs=1; input newname :$32. @@; run;
proc transpose data=want(obs=1) out=oldnames name=oldname; var _all_; run;
filename rename temp;
data renames; 
  merge oldnames newnames end=eof; 
  *no by statement; 
  file rename; 
  if _n_=1 then put 'rename';
  if upcase(oldname) ne upcase(newname) then 
     put oldname :$quote. +(-1) 'n=' newname :$quote. +(-1) 'n' 
  ;
  if eof then put ';' ;
run;
proc dataset lib=WORK nolist;
  modify want;
%include rename / source2;
run;quit;
```

Comment: Thank you the DSD did the trick for getting the data to read in properly. It's such a pain and no way to change the datafile output from another system apparently.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by cutoff? Are the variable names shortened to 32 characters, or are column names beyond a certain point in the first line not even read in ?

Try

```
filename myfile '... the full filename ...` lrecl=1000000;
proc import dbms=csv datafile=myfile ...
```

Comment: What I mean is that the record length is more than 32767 (or whatever the largest number is) so then the column names don't get read in properly and they're read in as VAR342, VAR343 - VAR2402. When I run the above this doesn't change my problem unfortunately.

Comment: PROC IMPORT cannot handle header lines that are longer than 32,767 bytes.

Comment: @Tom yes this is the issue I'm trying to overcome.

Comment: Use %CSV2DS() macro instead of PROC IMPORT.  Or just write your own data step.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a similar way to use `Proc DATASETS` to rename the columns after using `Proc IMPORT` to read the data portion of the csv file.

```
filename csv 'c:\temp\wide.csv' lrecl=1000000;
data _null_;
  file csv dsd dlm=',';
  if _n_ = 1 then do;
    put 'id'@@;
    do i = 1 to 5000;
      put ',My!#Column_' i +(-1) @@ ;  * weird column names in data;
    end;
    put;
  end;
  do id = 1 to 25;
    put 'id' id z18. @ ;
    array x x1-x5000;
    do over x;
      k + 1 ;
      x = k ;
    end;
    put ',' x(*);
  end;
run;

proc import datafile=csv dbms=csv replace out=imported;
  datarow = 2;
  getnames = no;
run;

data headers;
  infile csv dsd obs=1;
  length name newname $32;
  name = cats('var',_n_);
  input newname @@;
  newname = compress(newname,,'kflud');  * keep only SAS name parts of column names ;
  if _n_ = 1 then call execute('proc datasets noprint lib=work;modify imported;rename ');
  call execute(catx('=',name,newname));
run;
;quit;
```